# How to add fade in to this jQuery function?

Tags: jquery, background, slideshow

I have made below code to change background images, but I would like to also animate it to fadeout old slide and fade in new one. The problem is, that I don't really know how can I achieve this... Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var slideshow = $(".slideshow");
        var slides = new Array("url(../images/slideshow/fota1.jpg)","url(../images/slideshow/fota2.jpg)");
        var current = 0;

    function nextSlide() {
        slideshow.css("background",slides[current = ++current % slides.length]);

        setTimeout(nextSlide, 5000);
    }
    setTimeout(nextSlide, 5000);
    slideshow.css("background", slides[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery's `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()` functions to accomplish this sort of animation. Just set the background image in the fadeOut callback so that the animations are queued up in order:

```
$(function(){

    var slideshow = $('.slideshow'),
        slides = new Array('url(http://placehold.it/350x150)', 'url(http://placehold.it/350x150/250)'),
        current = 0;    

    function nextSlide(){
        // fade out, with callback
        slideshow.fadeOut(800, function(){
            slideshow.css('background',slides[current = ++current % slides.length]);
        });
        //fade in 
        slideshow.fadeIn(800);
    }

    setTimeout(nextSlide, 5000);
    slideshow.css('background', slides[0]);
});
```

And a working snippet:

```js
$(function(){
    
    var slideshow = $('.slideshow'),
        slides = new Array('url(http://placehold.it/350x150)', 'url(http://placehold.it/350x150/250)'),
        current = 0; 
    
    function nextSlide(){
     slideshow.fadeOut(800, function(){
         slideshow.css('background',slides[current = ++current % slides.length]);
        });
        slideshow.fadeIn(800);
    }
    
    setTimeout(nextSlide, 5000);
    slideshow.css('background', slides[0]);
});
```

```css
div{
    height: 150px;
    width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideshow"></div>
```